why is this modelmapper mapping failing?
I'm trying to map a json pojo to an xml pojo using ModelMapper...
In the code, below, I was expecting to see the content of "jsonSource" (source) POJO transferred to xmlDest POJO (target)
...however, the code fails - as no data in ("jsonSource") was reflected in the target ("xml").   i.e., as the difference in the ".size()" method value indicates.
SOURCE (json)
jsonSource.getEmployees().size() == 2

TARGET (xml)
xml.getEmployees().size() == 0    <<< should also be 2

code snippet...
    @Test
    public void givenJsonSource_whenMapToXmlDest_thenFieldsMapCorrectly() throws Exception {

        Employees jsonSource = new Employees();
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.setName("thename");
        employee1.setGender("M");
        employee1.setAge(30);
        employees.add(employee1);

        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.setName("thename2");
        employee2.setGender("M2");
        employee2.setAge(32);
        employees.add(employee2);

        jsonSource.setEmployees(employees);

        aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employees xml = mapper.map(jsonSource, aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employees.class);

        System.out.println("jsonSource.getEmployees().size()=>" + jsonSource.getEmployees().size());  // <<< 2
        System.out.println("xmlDest.getEmployee().size()=>" + xml.getEmployees().size());  // <<< 0


        // verify fields
        assertEquals(xml.getEmployees().get(0).getName(), jsonSource.getEmployees().get(0).getName());
    }
    

...although jsonSource.getEmployees().size is 2, the   xmlDest.getEmployee.size() is 0
Here is the Employee json pojo class (referenced above)...
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.jar;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

    public class Employee {

        @JsonProperty("name") 
        String name;
        @JsonProperty("gender")     
        String gender;
        @JsonProperty("age")     
        Integer age;
        
        public Employee() {
        }
        public Employee(String name, String gender, Integer age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.age = age;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee{" + "name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", age=" + age + '}';
        }

    }

Here is the Employees json POJO class...
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.jar;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

    @JsonRootName(value = "Employees")
    public class Employees {
        
        @JsonProperty(value = "Employees")
        protected List<Employee> employees;

        public Employees() {
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            if (employees == null) {
                employees = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            return this.employees;
        }

        public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
            this.employees = employees;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employees{" + "employees=" + employees + '}';
        }
        
    }

Here is the generated xml POJO (aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employee)
    //
    // This file was generated by the Eclipse Implementation of JAXB, v3.0.0 
    // See https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri 
    // Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
    // Generated on: 2024.04.12 at 08:27:40 AM EDT 
    //


    package aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated;

    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


    /**
     * <p>Java class for Employee complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType name="Employee"&gt;
     *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
     *       &lt;all&gt;
     *         &lt;element name="Name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
     *         &lt;element name="Gender" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
     *         &lt;element name="Age" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
     *       &lt;/all&gt;
     *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
     *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
     * &lt;/complexType&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "Employee", propOrder = {

    })
    public class Employee {

        @XmlElement(name = "Name")
        protected String name;
        @XmlElement(name = "Gender")
        protected String gender;
        @XmlElement(name = "Age")
        protected Integer age;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the name property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the name property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setName(String value) {
            this.name = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the gender property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the gender property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setGender(String value) {
            this.gender = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the age property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link Integer }
         *     
         */
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the age property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link Integer }
         *     
         */
        public void setAge(Integer value) {
            this.age = value;
        }

    }

Here is the generated xml pojo (i.e., aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employees)
    //
    // This file was generated by the Eclipse Implementation of JAXB, v3.0.0 
    // See https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri 
    // Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
    // Generated on: 2024.04.12 at 08:27:40 AM EDT 
    //


    package aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType&gt;
     *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
     *       &lt;sequence&gt;
     *         &lt;element name="Employees" type="{http://www.aaa.bbb.ccc/jar/mmdemo}Employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
     *       &lt;/sequence&gt;
     *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
     *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
     * &lt;/complexType&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "employees"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Employees")
    public class Employees {

        @XmlElement(name = "Employees")
        protected List<Employee> employees;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the employees property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the Jakarta XML Binding object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the employees property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getEmployees().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link Employee }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            if (employees == null) {
                employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            }
            return this.employees;
        }

    }

this is the xsd used to generate the XML classes
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema 
        targetNamespace="http://www.aaa.bbb.ccc/jar/mmdemo"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        xmlns:es="http://www.aaa.bbb.ccc/jar/mmdemo"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                
        <xs:complexType name="Employee">
            <xs:all>
                
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Gender" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                                        
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:element name="Employees">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Employees" type="es:Employee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

    </xs:schema>

appreciate any help/hints at understanding what might be missing that would make the above work

Do you have a better problem description than “however, the code fails”?

I expected both  jsonSource.getEmployees().size()  and   xml.getEmployees().size()) to both be the same (i.e., 2).    this would be an indication that data from "jsonSource" (source) object now existed in "xml" (target/destination).    but "xml" size() was  0 (zero)  - rather than 2.

Your code snippet refers to class named EmployeesType but there is no such class.

should be updated now.  thx

looks like "a" solution is to individually map elements of Employees in a for-loop...
        for (Employee sourceEmployee : sourceEmployees) {
            aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employee destEmployee = mapper.map(sourceEmployee, aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employee.class);
            xml.getEmployees().add(destEmployee);
        }   

almost certainly it's not necessarily the only solution
-but, it works now....
    @Test
    public void givenJsonSource_whenMapToXmlDest_thenFieldsMapCorrectly() throws Exception {

        Employees jsonSource = new Employees();
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.setName("thename");
        employee1.setGender("M");
        employee1.setAge(30);
        employees.add(employee1);

        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.setName("thename2");
        employee2.setGender("M2");
        employee2.setAge(32);
        employees.add(employee2);

        jsonSource.setEmployees(employees);
        
        aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employees xml = new aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employees();
        
        List<Employee> sourceEmployees = jsonSource.getEmployees();
        for (Employee sourceEmployee : sourceEmployees) {
            aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employee destEmployee = mapper.map(sourceEmployee, aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.generated.Employee.class);
            xml.getEmployees().add(destEmployee);
        }        

        System.out.println("jsonSource.getEmployees().size()=>" + jsonSource.getEmployees().size());
        System.out.println("xmlDest.getEmployee().size()=>" + xml.getEmployees().size());


        // verify fields
        assertEquals(xml.getEmployees().get(0).getName(), jsonSource.getEmployees().get(0).getName());
    }

